# Get InputStream of a class that is dynamically created (using bytecode)?

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

I create a class dynamically - by constructing the bytecode and loading it with class loader. Later, I need to get `InputStream` of this class. With common class, I get this by getting resource `URL` for this class and then opening the stream (`url.openStream()`). Obviously, here I can't do that, as dynamically loaded class does not have the URL.

How can I get `InputStream` of dynamically created class?

The only solution I can think of atm is to save the bytecodes to some temp file/memory and then to provide `InputStream` from it.

EDIT

I need `InputStream` to make another bytecode change on top of existing.

Comment: If you have the bytecode as a `byte[]` then you could construct a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: I do have it, but it's generated on different place of the app and in different time. If I start to collect all the `byte[]` for each proxy class it is generated, it's going to be too much. Anyway, I am exploring this option.

Comment: Since you don't explicitly state what you need to do with the InputStream, I can only guess, but ObjectInputStream may be helpful? ref: [javadoc for ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)

Comment: @mangotang thanx - but no, I need it for further bytecode change (question updated)

Comment: First of all, you should get rid of the intermediate `URL` step, as that requires defining a custom protocol and implementing a protocol handler for in-memory representations. Just use, e.g. `Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("Foo.class")`. That way, the `ClassLoader` can return a `ByteArrayInputStream` without the need to support `URL`s. If you change it to use temporary files to save memory in-between, the application logic doesn’t change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class loader does not provide a class's byte code via either `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` (this is legal, the class loader contract does not specify such a thing), you can still u[se a Java agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) for asking the VM to create the byte code for you.

For example, you can register the following transformer:

```
instrumentation.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
  @Override
  public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader,
                          String name,
                          Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                          ProtectionDomain pd,
                          byte[] classFileBuffer) {
    doSomethingWith(classFileBuffer);
    return null;
  }
}, true);
```

After attaching a Java agent, you can call: `instrumentation.retransform(someGeneratedClass)` to trigger the above class file transformer which will contain the generated type's class file even if it is not available from its class loader.

Comment: Heya Rafael! Thanx for the answer; just agent is not always available as an option. I solved my problem in other way, but still, i might collect generated bytecode in some temp files (unless they are created every time on usage)

Comment: does anybody created agent for this?

Comment: seems like this https://github.com/rmannibucau/dumping-javaagent
if it works

Comment: confirm. It works on Java16!